# How to simulate the Local Notification in apple Watch App?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, watchkit

I am trying to simulate the local notification view in apple watch simulator. Does any one known how to simulate the local notifications in apple watch ?

I have done some research for that but didn't found any answer for the above. There is a way to simulate the PUSH NOTIFICATION but not for the LOCAL NOTIFICATION.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html ?

Comment: There s no answer yet, but totally a valid question. How can this be closed as too broad ???

Comment: @Larme The link you have posted is for the PUSH NOTIFICATIONS not for the LOCAL NOTIFICATION

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is not possible to have a Watch app react to a `UILocalNotification` in the simulator. However, it is almost identical to reacting to a push notification, except it gets routed through a couple of different methods.

If you're presenting an actionable notification, your `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController` subclass would override [`-didReceiveLocalNotification:withCompletion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKUserNotificationInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKUserNotificationInterfaceController/didReceiveLocalNotification:withCompletion:) instead of [`-didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKUserNotificationInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKUserNotificationInterfaceController/didReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletion:).

If your Watch app is getting launched in response to interacting with one of your actionable notifications, then your root `WKInterfaceController` would implement [`-handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:) or [`-handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:), as appropriate.

From WatchKit's point-of-view, those are the only distinctions between remote and local notifications.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any another way to design and test the local notification view in watch app ?

Comment: @NSAnant by putting the payload of your local notification into the PushNotificationPayload.json file and pretending that it's a remote notification. The point of my answer was to show that local and remote notifications get treated almost identically by the OS, and so you can treat them as almost entirely interchangeable.

Comment: @DaveDeLong did u get local notification in watch simulator if so then reply with proper code for triggering local notification in watch. Please dont say about notification recieve delegate methods everybody knows abt recieving tell abt triggering notification in watch

Comment: well thats a pain in the arse

Comment: This is not strictly true since a local notification comes into the handlers as UILocalNotification while the remote notification comes in as [NSObject : AnyObject]

Answer (score 8):

1. Run your watch app (notification target) on simulator, dismiss the notification and stay on clock face.
2. Switch to iOS simulator and create a notification. For testing purposes setup fireDate to something reasonable like:

   `notification.fireDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(10)`
3. Here goes the trick. Hit ⌘L to lock iOS simulator.
4. Enjoy notification arriving to watch app.

Comment: Yes. This is what I wanted. I think this should be marked as the answer.