# Push Notifications on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

My app is waiting for review by Apple to be released and there is no setting to support Apple Watch inside my app. My question is: Is the notifications which come to device in which my app is installed will be automatically displayed also on Apple Watch without making any update/change for my app (Like adding Apple Watch as target)? If so, will push notification actions of my iOS app also be available (and functional of course) on Apple Watch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your notifications will show up on the Apple Watch automatically:

> If your iOS app supports local or remote notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times. When one of your app’s local or remote notification arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on Apple Watch.

Official reference: [Apple Watch Programming Guide - Notification Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH18-SW1)

Comment: Thank you. And what about the remote notification actions? Are they will be displayed also on Apple Watch? And if so, how can they be handled?

Comment: Have a look at the linked documentation, it's all there :-)

Comment: The question was asked before the Apple Watch was released, so the only information source was Apples official documentation (quoted and linked above) which states that notifications are automatically displayed on the watch. Have a look at this answer regarding local notifications on the watch simulator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27278093/396578 ... why the downvote?