# is it possible to send a local notification to apple watch simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, apple-watch

I am trying to send a simple local notification from iphone simulator to the apple watch simulator.I tried it using a UILocalNotification class but it is showing a notification only on iphone but not on apple watch simulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate the Local Notification in apple Watch App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188862/how-to-simulate-the-local-notification-in-apple-watch-app)

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported at the moment. To view and test your Notification Interface on the Watch Simulator, specify a payload file, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html).

Anyway, when your app is released, the watch documentation says, iOS will decide itself where the notfication is sent, to the phone and/or the watch.