# How to show notifications in iWatch?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, watchkit

I am working on an iWatch application. I am doing a sample app using swift and my requirement is to display LocalNotifications. When i run my app in my iPhone simulator i’m getting the notifications but i'm not getting notifications when i run the app in iWatch simulator. Can any one explain me about how local notifications display in iWatch.
Do we need to design any UI to show the notifications on iWatch i.e static or dynamic interfaces in iWatch Interface builder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188862/how-to-simulate-the-local-notification-in-apple-watch-app

Answer (score 0):

- Run your watch app Select notification target on simulator, dismiss the notification and stay on clock face.

  - Hit ⌘L to lock iOS simulator.
  - Enjoy notification arriving to watch app.