# Can I test local notifications on the WatchOS 2 Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification, watchos-2, watchos-simulator

I am Googling a lot to find out way to check local notifications on the WatchOS Simulator because I don't have an iWatch. Right now I have implemented local notification but due some reason notification is shown on iPhone simulator but not on iWatch (WatchOS 2) simulator.

I have added following code in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:kAction1];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:kAction2];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:kAction3];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2]
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

Have you been able to get notifications for WatchOS local notifications in the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your watch app on simulator, from `iPhone` simulator schedule the `notification` and lock the `iPhone` simulator screen, keep the watch simulator active, in that case when notification is triggered , it will be delivered on your `watch` simulator. Same will be the case when you will test on actual devices.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a Watch app simulator react to a UILocalNotification. However, it is almost identical to reacting to a push notification, except it gets routed through a couple of different methods.

below answer will be helpful:
Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278093/2798877